# Set Ubuntu 20.04 grub screen color to default purple

Tags: grub2, 20.04, plymouth

I have a black grub screen, coming from the original install, which was Kubuntu. I now added Ubuntu-desktop, and I want grub to have the default Ubuntu purple background.

I executed below command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
```

I am getting below output.

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3.css
```

Comment: This was a Kubuntu install, and I added ubuntu-desktop. I edited the OP to reflect that.

Comment: Ok, can you check in this forum how to change grub backgroud color? you will have few answers which will work.

Comment: Kubuntu's implementation of GRUB has a black background.  This is the default.

Comment: I know that Kubuntu default is black, but I want the purple Ubuntu background. I tried a few answers given in the forum and I still have a black background. If someone has the magic formula for Ubuntu 20.04, please share it.

Comment: I thought the black grub background indicated UEFI install and the purple indicated legacy BIOS, or is that JUST for the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did It in my installation of Ubuntu 20.04 in this way:

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub`

And put the following lines:

```
if background_color 44,0,30 ; then
  clear
fi
```

(44,0,30) is the RGB code of the dark aubergine color according to the official Ubuntu color palette: https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette/

Then, update grub with:

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it is so close, it would be unfair not to accept it! However, the purple I see in the rest of the Ubuntu boot sequence is a little darker and drier. Maybe someone knows the exact numbers to make it look exactly right?

Comment: Check here the official Ubuntu color palette: https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette/ The color you are looking for is the dark aubergine, I suppose. Hex code is #2C001E that becomes (44, 0, 30) in the RGB format

Comment: See also https://www.color-hex.com/color/2c001e

Comment: Yes, you got the right color. The hue seems to change in RGB for some reason. Does it work better to use the Hex code?

Comment: I don't know if the color code can be put in hex format. However (44, 0, 30) is the exact convertion in decimal format of #2c001e, so the only chance that you have is to play with the RGB and find the shade you prefer